# Where can i place static contents under Jetty webserver?

Tags: web-services, jetty

i need to place some static contents under jetty directory , anybody knows where to place them ?

Answer (score 0):

You can compile the static files in a WAR and deploy the war in your webapps folder. A request for a URL path that matches a path to a file in the WAR is considered a static file. HTH